# appt-get results in connection timeout when trying to instal google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, proxy, apt-get

I do have a socket proxy that capable of accessing to google service. I am also trying install google gcloud-cli. Using the proxy because I am in mainland china.

According to the shell output, accessing to `packages.cloud.google.com`  using apt-get results in a connection timeout error, but it success while using curl command directly.
Can anyone help explain this error and the solution for this one? thanks

```
(base) ➜  /tmp echo $https_proxy
http://127.0.0.1:1082/
(base) ➜  /tmp sudo apt-get update                   
Hit:1 https://mirrors.aliyun.com/kubernetes/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                  
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Hit:9 http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                               
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/hluk/copyq/ubuntu jammy InRelease          
Ign:11 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease                                                                                                                                              
Ign:11 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease
Ign:11 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease
Err:11 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease
  Could not connect to packages.cloud.google.com:443 (142.251.42.238). - connect (110: Connection timed out)
Fetched 1,557 B in 2min 17s (11 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/cloud-sdk/InRelease  Could not connect to packages.cloud.google.com:443 (142.251.42.238). - connect (110: Connection timed out)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
(base) ➜  /tmp curl https://packages.cloud.google.com                                         

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Index of /</h1>
  <table>
   <tr><td><a href="/apt">apt</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td><a href="/yuck">yuck</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td><a href="/yum">yum</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td><a href="/yum-legacy">yum-legacy</a></td></tr>
</table>
<i></i>
</body></html>
(base) ➜  /tmp
```